# Provider 'xx' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my angular service:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('partyService', function($http) {
        this.fetch = function() {
            return $http.get('/api/parties')
                        .then(function(response) {
                            return response.data;
                        });
        }
    });
```

I think this service is returning data (or an empty array // not sure)

Then why am I geeting this error:

> Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'partyService' must return a value from $get factory method.

**Update:**

If I use service instead of factory then I don't get any errors. Why so???

Comment: Answering the update:
factory() and service() return different values by design. From https://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/ I found this:

```When you’re using a Factory you create an object, add properties to it, then return that same object. 

```When you’re using Service, it’s instantiated with the ‘new’ keyword. Because of that, you’ll add properties to ‘this’ and the service will return ‘this’.

I don't have an explanation; this is just the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error speaks for itself. You **must** return something in your factory:

```
var factory = {
  fetch: fetch
};

return factory;

function fetch() {
  return..
}
```

Then, in your `controller`:

```
partyService.fetch()...
```

Comment: Yup, that works very well. Thank you. I never knew that my factory was not returning anything. I only thought that I have two return statements inside the factory so, I am returning the data.

Answer (score 6):

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.factory('partyService', function($http) {

    function fetch = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/parties')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
    }

    function anotherFetch = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/parties')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     return response.data;
                 });
    }

  return {
    fetch,
    anotherFetch,
  }


});
```