# To implement factory pattern in the angularjs1 example

Tags: angularjs

I have written a code that uses a .factory notation and thus implements factory pattern. On a short note, the program checks if the number is Prime and als checks Is the cube an even number. I have done it via separate controllers.I want to know what went wrong in the code as i am getting the output error as - Provider 'MathService' must return a value from $get factory method.
Please help.

code-

```
 <html ng-app="Swabhav.ServiceApp">
 <head>
    <title> Factory Pattern </title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
     </head>

    <body>
     var oneModule=angular.module("Swabhav.ServiceApp",[]);

     oneModule.factory("MathService",["$log",function($log){

      $log.log("Inside Math Service");

    var techlabs=function(){
     var obj={};

      obj.isPrime=function(number){
        for(var index=2;index<number;index++){
            if(number%index==0){
                console.log("Is not a prime number");
                $log.log("inside $log - is not a prime");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
             }
        }

     obj.isCubeEvenNo=function(number){

        var cube=(number*number*number);

        if(cube%2==0){
            console.log("cube is even");
            $log.log("inside $log - is not a even number");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
        return obj;

    };


     }]);


     oneModule.controller("FirstController",
          ["$scope","MathService",function($scope){

     console.log($scope.isPrime(10));

     console.log($scope.isPrime(13));


    }]);


        oneModule.controller("SecondController",
     ["$scope","MathService",function($scope){

            console.log($scope.isCubeEvenNo(2));

            console.log($scope.isCubeEvenNo(7));

          }]);

     <div ng-controller="FirstController">

        <input type="text" ng-model="forprime">
        <button type="button" ng-
     click="techlabs.isPrime(forprime)">Check</button>

      </div>

    </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Please, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884434/provider-xx-must-return-a-value-from-get-factory-method

Comment: i changed ...still getting error - $scope.isPrime is not a function. I removed the var techlabs=function(){}